# how to get multiple rowID in jQGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-formatter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHw9B.png)

when click multiple check box then how to get multiple RowID in jqGrid

- Code:

  function BindMainGrid(rowDataMain) {
      debugger;
      $grid = $("#GetpassTable");
      $grid.jqGrid({
          loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
              alert('load error: ' + error);
          },
          colNames: ["Mail","GetPassID", "IMNumber", "UserID", "Item Description", "AssetTag","Unit","Quanity","Reason For Movement","Requisitioner","To be Carried By","From Location","From Sub Location","To Location","To Sub Location"],
          colModel: [

  ```
       { name: 'Mail', index: 'Mail', sorttype: 'text', width: '60px', formatter: RenderMail },
          { "name": "GetPassID", "index": "GetPassID", "width": "150", hidden: true },

          { "name": "IMNumber", "index": "IMNumber", "width": "150"},
           { "name": "UserID", "index": "UserID", "width": "150" },
           { "name": "Item_Description", "index": "Item_Description", "width": "300" },
            { "name": "AssetTag", "index": "AssetTag", "width": "500" },

             { "name": "Unit", "index": "Unit", "width": "150" },
           { "name": "Quanity", "index": "Quanity", "width": "150" },
           { "name": "Reason_For_Movement", "index": "Reason_For_Movement", "width": "350" },
            { "name": "Requisitioner", "index": "Requisitioner", "width": "200" },

          { "name": "ToBeCarriedBy", "index": "ToBeCarriedBy", "width": "150" },
           { "name": "FromLocation", "index": "FromLocation", "width": "150" },
            { "name": "FromSubLocation", "index": "FromSubLocation", "width": "150" },

             { "name": "ToLocation", "index": "ToLocation", "width": "150" },
            { "name": "ToSubLocation", "index": "ToSubLocation", "width": "150" },


      ],


      data: rowDataMain,
      datatype: "local",
      editurl: 'Project Details',
      gridview: true,
      pgbuttons: true,
      rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
      rownum: 10,
      pager: '#GetpassPager',
      datapage: true,
      viewrecords: true,
      autowidth: true,
      height: "280px",
      loadtext: "Loading...",
      scroll: false,
      pageable: true,
      pagerpos: 'center',
      caption: "Get pass Generation",
      multiselect: false,
      loadonce: false,
      forceFit: false,
      ignoreCase: true,
      jsonReader: {
          page: function (obj) { return 1; },
          total: function (obj) { return 1; },
          records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; },
          root: function (obj) { return obj.d; },
          repeatitems: false,
          id: "0"
      },
      shrinkToFit: false,
      loadComplete: function (data) {

      },
  }).navGrid("#GetpassPager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false }, {}, {}, {}, { modal: true, multipleSearch: true })
  ```

  }

  ```
  function RenderMail(cellValue, options, subrowData, rowObject) {
  var radioHtml = '<input style="width:25px" type="Checkbox" value=' + cellValue + ' name="Checkid" onclick="chk(\'' + options.subgrid_id + '\')"></input>';


  return radioHtml;
  ```

  }

  function chk(rowId) {

  }

Comment: Kindly paste the code here

Comment: I post my code as above

Answer (score 0):

Try this using JQUERY

```
$('#GetpassTable input:checkbox').each(function(i){

console.log($(this).prop('checked')+' '+i);
})
```

To fetch id on checkbox click try this

```
$(document).on('click','#GetpassTable tbody input:checkbox',function(){
console.log('clicked id : '+$(this).closest('tr').prop('id'));
});
```

Kindly see console window if you're getting any errors

Comment: It depends you can write it on button click to fetch all the selected index

Comment: yes , it's working but when click on check box  then how to get cell value of that row